# Symfony2 Multiple File Upload was not found in the chain configured namespaces exception

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, doctrine-orm

So I've been working on getting my website to upload multiple files at once, and I've gotten pretty close (I think), but I'm getting the following error "The class 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' was not found in the chain configured namespaces". I think it's because I'm uploading the file as

```
$data = $form->getData();
$files = $data['file'];

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $photo = new Photo();
    $photo->setFile($file);
    $em->persist($file);
}
```

instead of connecting $photo to the createFormBuilder, if that makes any sense. I'm not sure what to do here, since I don't want to loose the auto_mapping from doctrine. Is there another workaround here, to make doctrine map UploadedFile? Here's my full code

[Controller](http://pastebin.com/jrU9tERs)

[Entity](http://pastebin.com/1E96LWYy)

[Photo Entity YML](http://pastebin.com/i2ntVpCK)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this. Doctrine tries to persist `UploadedFile` class and it is not entity class at all.

Possible workarounds:

- Save the filename
- Save the file content (BLOB data)

Generally, the easier way is to save file name only, BUT, you also need to move file, since the file is being uploaded to `/tmp` by default. Failing to move it will result in losing the file altogether.

`UploadedFile` comes with useful method `move` which you could use to achieve file relocation.

### Another solution (less code but far more complex):

About a week ago I released my own bundle that handles file uploads. You can find it here: https://github.com/jperovic/exploring-fileutility

It tackles with this issue by moving the file and giving you the file name so you could write it to the database

**Disclaimer:** it is not my intention to hijack you question with bundle promotion. Just say the word and I will remove it from answer.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to put the doctrine config file for my entity in. I've done all of that. I've got preUpload using the prePersist hook and upload using the postPersist hook. I go for the first method. The upload works when I tie my Photo entity into the form builder, it's when I try to persist my object manually like above that I get this problem. I would use a bundle, but I want to understand how to do it standalone first

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm giving you an up anyway, because you're post was very informative, but when it came down to it, it was a stupid typo

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I'm just an idiot. Spent hours trying to figure it out, only to find out that I was doing

```
$em->persist($file);
```

instead of

```
$em->persist($photo);
```

My bad